# PHP echo statement with URL parameter

Tags: php, curl, docker, http-post

I wrote a mini script in PHP to send a POST request to the web server:

```
<?php

$cid = file_get_contents('cid');

function httpPost($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

echo httpPost("http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$cid/stop?t=5");

?>
```

Yes, this is Docker.  I'm using the [remote API in Docker](http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/docker/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-docker-remote-api), and this little piece of script works!
**However, the ?t=5 at the end of the URL, gets ignored.**
I guess it has to do with the **?**.

How do I get this URL properly formatted, so that the ?t=5 works correctly?

(I tried 1,001 ways so far, with quotes and double quotes, with no luck.  After more than 4 hours spent on this, I thought stackoverflow could help?)

Thanks...

NOTE: the "cid" is only a file on the hard-drive, that stores the container id.  So I'm retrieving the container id from the file, and passing it to the URL (this part works, anyway).
The complete URL is written by me, i.e. not parsed.

Comment: Have your tried this? `$ch = curl_init($url);` I'm not sure but this might change the things.

Comment: don't know anything about Docker so this might not work in your case but if the URL is parsed with mod_rewrite you need to add the option [QSA] in the .htaccess to pass get paramters

Comment: Does the `stop` script expect the `t` parameter to be in `GET` or `POST` data? Putting it after `?` puts it in the `GET` data.

Comment: Well, this works as command-line: `curl -v --raw -X POST http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/79dbbc471a4a/stop?t=5`.  So I found one way to have the container ID "dynamic".  Then, I was looking online for a way to construct a proper cURL function in PHP.  This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Hey tux, updated the answer below. You're missing CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: @mikesp Docker is written in Go so it has easy access to create it's own http server. The default http listen port is 2375 (if http is enabled) so it's likely in this case that Apache is not involved.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no special requirements on your URL, why use an incomplete cURL wrapper function? You can simply do

```
echo file_get_contents("http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$cid/stop?t=5");
```

To answer your actual question as to why your query string gets ignored, it is because it is not being sent to the server properly. Google **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**

**Edit** Since it was mentioned that the request method has to be POST, you can change things a little in your cURL code to cater for that

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"t=5");
```

Then you can call your function like

```
echo httpPost("http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$cid/stop");
```

Comment: container stop is a POST endpoint https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/#stop-a-container

Answer (score 1):

You might try executing like this?

```
<?php
$cid = file_get_contents('cid');

function containeraction($cid, $action, $s) {
    //Time in Seconds
    $timedelay="t=".$s;
    //Docker Container Host
    $dockerhost="172.17.0.1";
    //Host Port
    $port="2375";
    $url = "http://".$dockerhost.":".$port."/containers/".$cid."/".$action;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $timedelay);
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

//containeraction(container id, action, delay)
echo containeraction($cid, "stop", "5");

?>
```

Comment: ummm thanks for this, but the URL parameter still gets ignored.

Comment: Oh my apologies I'll get back to you in a few minutes then

Comment: What did you change other than using concatenation instead of interpolation for the `$cid` variable? Why would that make a difference?

Comment: I think we're getting close to it, with Steve's code.  However, the URL gets executed, ignoring the URL parameter again! (this t=5 is supposed to give a 5 sec pause before stopping the container)

Comment: I just realized what this was for... one moment

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying a POST request you can modify your function a bit. For $data you can pass array("t"=>5).

```
function httpPost($url, $data = '')
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    if ($data != '')
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind completing your piece of code, so that I can see how you construct the result URL?  (I'm really a noob in PHP)

Comment: he means, echo httpPost("http:// 172.17.0.1:2375 / containers/ $cid/stop", array("t"=>5)); -- I had to put some spaces before/after slashes because it kept breaking the full syntax.

Comment: How does `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` modify the query string?

Answer (score 0):

Your curl setup works against Docker and passes the query string. You do need to trim whitespace when reading files in case there is a new line at the end.

```
<?php

$cid = trim(file_get_contents('cid'));
echo "$cid\n";

function httpPost($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$url = "http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$cid/stop?t=6";
echo "$url\n";
echo httpPost($url)

?>
```

Comment: HI , how can I pass the parameter without "?"
e.g  $url = "http://172.17.0.1:2375/containers/$cid/stop and 
$param = "6" and we can receive the 6 on the receiving script ?
Here is my question if you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930240/php-curl-post-value-without-querystring-parameter